# Sequelize: user_favorites table shared by item_id with multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

In the past, I was creating a separate favorites table for each entity that a user could "favorite". The things a user can favorite for now are `dry_foods` and `frozen_foods`.

I wanted to create a single `user_favorites` table that can reference either `dry_foods.id` or `frozen_foods.id` by `user_favorites.item_id`.

Here is a quick sketch of the relationship that I'm trying to convey.

[image: diagram of models]

- All `users` can have many `user_favorites`.
- `user_favorites` belongs to either `frozen_foods` or `dry_foods`

`UserFavorite` model:

```
export default class UserFavorite extends Model {
  public id!: number
  public item_id!: number
  public category_id!: number
  public user_id!: number

  public static associations: {
    User: Association<UserFavorite, User>
    Category: Association<UserFavorite, Category>
    DryFood: Association<UserFavorite, DryFood>
    FrozenFood: Association<UserFavorite, FrozenFood>
  }

  public static associate(models: any) {
   this.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'user_id',
      as: 'user',
    })
   this.belongsTo(models.Category, {
      foreignKey: 'category_id',
      as: 'category',
    })
    this.belongsTo(models.FrozenFood, {
      foreignKey: 'item_id',
    })
    this.belongsTo(models.DryFood, {
      foreignKey: 'item_id',
    })
  })
```

`FrozenFood` model:

```
export default class FrozenFood extends Model {
  public id!: number
  public category_id!: number

  public static associations: {
    UserFavorite: Association<FrozenFood, UserFavorite>
    Category: Association<FrozenFood, Category>
  }

  public static associate(models: any) {
      this.belongsTo(models.UserFavorite, {
        foreignKey: 'id',
      })
      this.belongsTo(models.Category, {
        foreignKey: 'category_id',
          as: 'category',
      })
  })
```

`DryFood` model:

```
export default class DryFood extends Model {
  public id!: number
  public category_id!: number

  public static associations: {
    UserFavorite: Association<DryFood, UserFavorite>
    Category: Association<DryFood, Category>
  }

  public static associate(models: any) {
      this.belongsTo(models.UserFavorite, {
        foreignKey: 'id',
      })
      this.belongsTo(models.Category, {
        foreignKey: 'category_id',
          as: 'category',
      })
  })
```

Now, when I query with the following:

```
   const results = await UserFavorite.findAll({
        include: [{
          model: DryFood,
          include: [{
            model: Category,
            as: 'category',
          }]
        }]
      })
```

I get my desired result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 7,
    "category_id": 4,
    "item_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2022-01-12T06:15:18.419Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-01-12T06:15:18.419Z",
    "user_id": 1,
    "DryFood": {
      "id": 1,
      "category_id": 14,
      "created_at": "2022-01-09T18:17:14.115Z",
      "name": "Mac & Cheese",
      "updated_at": "2022-01-09T18:17:14.115Z",
      "user_id": 1,
      "category": {
        "id": 14,
        "created_at": "2022-01-09T18:17:13.349Z",
        "updated_at": "2022-01-09T18:17:13.349Z",
        "parent_id": 4,
        "title": null,
        "slug": "dry-food"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But when I try to also query for `frozen_foods`:

```
   const results = await UserFavorite.findAll({
        include: [{
          model: DryFood,
          include: [{
            model: Category,
            as: 'category',
          }]
        }, {
          model: FrozenFood,
          include: [{
            model: Category,
            as: 'category',
        }]
      })
```

I get the following error:

```
error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "FrozenFood"
```

Here is the failed generated query:

```
SELECT "UserFavorite"."id",
       "UserFavorite"."category_id",
       "UserFavorite"."item_id",
       "UserFavorite"."created_at",
       "UserFavorite"."updated_at",
       "UserFavorite"."user_id",
       "DryFood"."id" AS "DryFood.id",
       "DryFood"."category_id" AS "DryFood.category_id",
       "DryFood"."created_at" AS "DryFood.created_at",
       "DryFood"."description" AS "DryFood.description",
       "DryFood"."cleaned_description" AS "DryFood.cleaned_description",
       "DryFood"."name" AS "DryFood.name",
       "DryFood"."subtitle" AS "DryFood.subtitle",
       "DryFood"."photo" AS "DryFood.photo",
       "DryFood"."slug" AS "DryFood.slug",
       "DryFood"."status" AS "DryFood.status",
       "DryFood"."updated_at" AS "DryFood.updated_at",
       "DryFood"."user_id" AS "DryFood.user_id",
       "DryFood->category"."id" AS "DryFood.category.id",
       "DryFood->category"."created_at" AS "DryFood.category.created_at",
       "DryFood->category"."updated_at" AS "DryFood.category.updated_at",
       "DryFood->category"."status" AS "DryFood.category.status",
       "DryFood->category"."type" AS "DryFood.category.type",
       "DryFood->category"."name" AS "DryFood.category.name",
       "DryFood->category"."parent_id" AS "DryFood.category.parent_id",
       "DryFood->category"."title" AS "DryFood.category.title",
       "DryFood->category"."slug" AS "DryFood.category.slug",
       "DryFood->category"."extra_attributes" AS "DryFood.category.extra_attributes",
       "FrozenFood"."id" AS "FrozenFood.id",
       "FrozenFood"."created_at" AS "FrozenFood.created_at",
       "FrozenFood"."updated_at" AS "FrozenFood.updated_at",
       "FrozenFood"."deleted_at" AS "FrozenFood.deleted_at",
       "FrozenFood"."name" AS "FrozenFood.name",
       "FrozenFood"."category_id" AS "FrozenFood.category_id",
       "FrozenFood"."slug" AS "FrozenFood.slug",
       "FrozenFood"."status" AS "FrozenFood.status",
       "FrozenFood"."user_favorite_id" AS "FrozenFood.UserFavoriteId",
       "FrozenFood->category"."id" AS "FrozenFood.category.id",
       "FrozenFood->category"."created_at" AS "FrozenFood.category.created_at",
       "FrozenFood->category"."updated_at" AS "FrozenFood.category.updated_at",
       "FrozenFood->category"."status" AS "FrozenFood.category.status",
       "FrozenFood->category"."type" AS "FrozenFood.category.type",
       "FrozenFood->category"."name" AS "FrozenFood.category.name",
       "FrozenFood->category"."parent_id" AS "FrozenFood.category.parent_id",
       "FrozenFood->category"."title" AS "FrozenFood.category.title",
       "FrozenFood->category"."slug" AS "FrozenFood.category.slug",
       "FrozenFood->category"."extra_attributes" AS "FrozenFood.category.extra_attributes"
FROM "user_favorites" AS "UserFavorite"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "strains" AS "DryFood" ON "UserFavorite"."item_id" = "DryFood"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories" AS "FrozenFood->category" ON "FrozenFood"."category_id" = "FrozenFood->category"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "brands" AS "FrozenFood" ON "UserFavorite"."item_id" = "FrozenFood"."id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "categories" AS "FrozenFood->category" ON "FrozenFood"."category_id" = "FrozenFood->category"."id"
WHERE (("UserFavorite"."user_id" = 1));
```

Are my associations wrong? My query wrong? Ripping my hair out over here and about to just avoid the Sequelize magic and do a custom SQL query...

Comment: First of all please show the generated SQL (of course, formatted) that cased the error

Comment: Secondly, did you try `subquery: false` option in the top level options?

Comment: Thirdly, maybe you wish to look at this: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/polymorphic-associations.html

Comment: @Anatoly I have tried with both `subquery: false`, `required: false`/`required:true` and many other permutations. I have updated to show the failed generated SQL. Keep in mind I intentionally left off some fields in my model descriptions as you can see in the generated version.

Comment: Can you try different aliases for categories in `DryFood` and `FrozedFood`?

Comment: @Anatoly I tried that, which actually worked to an extent, but I think I needed `duplicating: false` or something to not link Frozen and Dry foods together. I've regressed to my original design and went ahead and made separate tables for each entity and their favorites. It ain't pretty but it works. Thanks for your help that polymorphic assocation is good.